# Quantum Physics question

Tags: equation-solving, functions, numerical-integration, numerics, integral-equations

I'm not sure if anyone here would be able to help me. But if you know a more appropriate place where I could ask for help, please let me know.
So here's the question:

[image]

And here's my attempt at solving it (part b where I have to find the actual matrix elements) relying on the example **[in this link](http://physicspages.com/2013/09/02/stark-effect-in-hydrogen-for-n-1-and-n-2/)**:

```
R30 = 2 (1/(3 a))^(3/2) (1 - (2 r)/(3 a) + (2 r^2)/(27 a^2)) E^(-(r/(3 a)));
R31 = (4 Sqrt[2])/9 (1/(3 a))^(3/2) r/a (1 - r/(6 a)) E^(-(r/(3 a)));
R32 = (2 Sqrt[2])/(27 Sqrt[5]) (1/(3 a))^(3/2) (r/a)^2 E^(-(r/(3 a)));
R = Rc = {R30, R31, R32};

h[x_, y_, z_, t_] :=
  Integrate[
    Rc[[x + 1]]
    SphericalHarmonicY[x,y, θ, ϕ]\[Conjugate]
    R[[z + 1]]
    SphericalHarmonicY[z, t, θ, ϕ]
    r^2 Sin[θ]
    , {r, 0, ∞}, {θ, 0, π}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}];

Print[h[0, 0, 1, 0]];
Print[h[1, 0, 2, 0]];
Print[h[1, 1, 2, 1]];
Print[h[1, -1, 2, -1]];
```

Unfortunately, the above outputs all 0's :( :( :(

[image]

Comment: It looks like the factor involving θ is a function that has equal positive and negatives bits, so it all integrates to zero.  For example, `h[0, 0, 1, 0]` has a `Cos[θ] Sin[θ]` factor.  Changing the range to `{θ, 0, π/2}` gives something more interesting, but I have no idea if that is a sensible thing to do for the problem.

Comment: You don't need to integrate over `\[Phi]` because all your matrix elements are between states that have the same `m`. You can therefore evaluate `Integrate[LegendreP[l1, m, Cos[\[Theta]]] Cos[\[Theta]] LegendreP[l2, m, Cos[\[Theta]]], {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}]` for various `l1`, `l2` and `m` to extract the results that you need.

Comment: Stephen Luttrell, even though m's are the same, the Spherical harmonics are different because of the different l's.
But thank you for your feedback. When I was thinking about what you said I double checked my work and found the error.
I forgot to include the actual z = r cos[theta] in the integral :( shame on me!
It seems to be working now :D

Comment: In the matrix element that I quoted `LegendreP[l, m, z]` is the associated Legendre polynomial which gives the `l` dependence of the corresponding spherical harmonic.

Answer (score 1):

There was a really silly mistake. I'm embarrassed for even asking now...
z = r cos[theta] was missing from the integral. It's all good now.
Thanks for the help anyways! Love you guys :]
[image]